# Naming convention for functions that mutate arguments vs creating a new object

Tags: c, naming-standards

Take the following signature

`BigInt* addBigInt(BigInt* arg1, BigInt* arg2);`

Traditionally, the safest way to implement this function would be for it not mutate the arguments, and would necessarily need to create a new object to result for the operation.  Alternatively, if the aim is to conserve on system memory, `arg1` could be the object that the resulting operation would return having mutated that object.

The question is, **is there an established naming convention the would delineate the nuance between the two implementation choices**?  Or is this something that would need to be clearly laid out in the documentation where the developer is establishing the convention?

Let's assume this is in C where function overloading is not possible.

Comment: I know of some other langauges that have conventions on this. Ruby uses `!` at the end of methods that operate in place (e.g. `array.sort!` vs `result = array.sort`), though you can't do that in C given that `!` isn't a valid character for an identifier name. I like Swift's convention though, "use the verb’s imperative for the mutating method and apply the “ed” or “ing” suffix to name its nonmutating counterpart." E.g. `array.sort()` vs `let result = array.sorted()` https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#use-terminology-well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a new object, return it.

```
public int[] square(int a[], int size)
{
   int b[] = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

   for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
       b[i] = a[i] * 2;

   return b;
}
```

If you don't create an object, return `void`.

```
public void square(int a[], int size)
{
   for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
       a[i] = a[i] * 2;
}
```

Note that programming languages that support method overloading don't usually distinguish between return types.  If you really need both functions, just change the name of one of them; perhaps `square` and `square_copy`.

Comment: Though this is a fine convention, note that most C functions like [strncat()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/) do not follow it.  They name arguments _source_ and _destination_ for clarity.

Comment: @user949300: Concatenation is not the same as creating a brand new array.  `strncat` modifies the destination string *in-place.*  That's why it returns `void`.

Comment: `strncat` both modifies the destination in place, _it also returns it_.  Which is arguably confusing, as your `void` convention is clearer.  However, as a "standard", it might be what many C programmers would expect.

Comment: @user949300: Ah, [I see that](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/).    Apparently I've been discarding the return value all this time.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you'd use `const` to indicate that a pointer argument is not mutable.  Using your `addBigInt` example, if you want to indicate that neither `*arg1` nor `*arg2` are mutable, you'd write

```
 BigInt *addBigInt( const BigInt *arg1, const BigInt *arg2 );
```

Any attempt to write to `*arg1` or `*arg2` in `addBigInt` should cause the compiler to issue a diagnostic (even if the actual arguments `arg1` and `arg2` point to are not `const`).  If you were going to write the function such that the result is stored in `*arg1`, you could do something like

```
BigInt *addBigInt( BigInt *arg1, const BigInt *arg2 );
```

You'd just return `arg1` rather than a new object.  However, that's not perfectly clear just from the signature - you'd want to add some documentation:

```
/**
 * Adds two BigInts together, result is stored in the object
 * pointed to by arg1
 *
 * Inputs:
 *    arg1 
 *    arg2 
 *
 * Outputs:
 *    arg1
 *
 * Return value: 
 *    arg1
 */
```

Note that `const` doesn't necessarily mean "put this thing in read-only memory" (although that may be the result), it just means "this thing is not meant to be written to, and flag any code that attempts to do so."

Basic rules of `const` and pointers:

```
 const T *p;  // p is a non-const pointer to const T; you can write to p, but not *p
 T const *p;  // same as above

 T * const p; // is a const pointer to non-const T; you can write to *p, but not p
 
 const T * const p; // p is a const pointer to const T; you cannot write to either p or *p
 T const * const p; // same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I have never thought about trying to find naming convention about that. But If the method is void we can speculate that it may be a **Procedure**.

If I am to name a procedure I would focus more on describing what it does. In my opinion, it is more common for a **Procedure** to do more than one thing compared to a function and then a procedure would benefit from a more descriptive name even if it does not start with a verb.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it super explicit that a function modifies its argument(s), you might name it `inplace_something()` or `something_inplace()` so the intention becomes apparent without looking at argument or result types which may not be immediately visible in the context of the call.